# unrecoverable failure in required component org.gnome.Shell.desktop

Tags: boot, gnome, 18.10

A laptop with a fresh installation of 18.10 would not boot to the desktop.
Subsequently, I started with options and viewed my logs (`journalctl -p err | grep gnome`) and saw this message produced for process `gnome-session-binary`:

```
Unrecoverable failure in required component org.gnome.Shell.desktop
```

Comment: You also get the [`CRITICAL: We failed, but the fail whale is dead. Sorry....`](https://askubuntu.com/a/662688/349837)? Please edit your question adding the enabled extensions? `gsettings get org.gnome.shell enabled-extensions | tr ', ' ',\n'`, might be useful also some info of your machine: `inxi -SCGM -! 31 -y 80`.