# Ubuntu 18.04 is crashing. Have no idea what's causing it

Tags: 18.04, nvidia, crash, amd-ryzen

I upgraded my desktop PC last June 21 to these specs:

Proc: Ryzen 5 2600 (stock Cooler)
MB: MSI B450 Bazooka Plus
RAM: Kingston Hyper X Fury 2x8gb 2666
GPU: GTX 1050
PSU: Seasonic S12? 80+ Bronze 520 Watts

And ever since, Ubuntu will randomly crash or hang? No display, no keyboard/mouse input (totally no power) and the CPU LED EZ DEBUG light from the MB is on.

I tried contacting MSI but they are giving me solutions for when the unit totally doesn't boot with the CPU LED on and for WINDOWS (argh!)

Below is the last part of syslog before crashing:

https://pastebin.com/vyHDDk9b

Comment: There were problems with Ryzen 5 and Linux and the C6 power state. ( [Discussion](https://www.reddit.com/r/Amd/comments/apw8im/ryzen_freezes_in_linux_even_if_linux_is_in_vm/) ). What is your Kernel version? Things went better with 4.19+ for me - in combination with the `idle=nomwait processor.max_cstate=5 rcu_nocbs=0-7` (8 virutal kernels) boot options.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/662678/critical-we-failed-but-the-fail-whale-is-dead-sorry

Comment: @Fiximan - Kernel version: 4.15.0-54-generic . TYVM, will try updating to 4.19+..

Comment: @karel okay... I'm lost.. Really sorry for being a noob :/

Answer (score 0):

I somewhat managed to fix it by reading the discussions provided by @Fiximan. Thanks again!

I did not update my kernel to 4.19+ nor add any boot option. I only changed a setting from my BIOS:

Power Supply Idle Control: [Auto] > Typical Current Idle

And no more overnight crash!

I read it from: https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=196683#c511.

From that Bugzilla report, what it does is currently unknown? But some speculations is that it disables C6 Power State though some reported that it doesn't.. ANYWAY, my problem is now solved!

Thanks everyone!