# What does the following logs mean?

Tags: drivers, 20.04, kernel, amd-processor, amd-ryzen

I am having HP Laptop with AMD Ryzen 5 processor. I was having screen freezing issue so, I updated Bios of my laptop to latest version. Still I am getting following `logs`:

```
11:17:25 kernel: iommu ivhd0: AMD-Vi: Event logged [INVALID_DEVICE_REQUEST device=00:00.0 pasid=0x00000 address=0xfffffffdf8000000 flags=0x0a00]
09:21:32 gnome-session-b: CRITICAL: We failed, but the fail whale is dead. Sorry....
09:21:27 gdm-session-wor: gkr-pam: unable to locate daemon control file
09:20:06 systemd: Failed to start Load/Save Screen Backlight Brightness of backlight:amdgpu_bl0.
09:20:06 systemd-backlig: amdgpu_bl0: Failed to write system 'brightness' attribute: No such device or address
09:20:06 systemd: Failed to start Load/Save Screen Backlight Brightness of backlight:acpi_video1.
09:20:06 systemd-udevd: could not read from '/sys/module/amd64_edac_mod/initstate': No such device
09:20:04 kernel: lis3lv02d: unknown sensor type 0x0
09:20:04 kernel: tpm_crb MSFT0101:00: can't request region for resource [mem 0xcd590000-0xcd590fff]
09:20:04 kernel: pci 0000:00:00.2: AMD-Vi: Unable to read/write to IOMMU perf counter.
09:20:04 kernel: __common_interrupt: 0.110 No irq handler for vector
```

1. What does each log mean?
2. Is it critical error?
3. How do I resolve if there is any issue?
4. Also, I noticed that the battery of my laptop drains quickly when using Ubuntu. Anyone can help to find out the reason?
5. Touchpad sometimes doesn't work and I have to restart the laptop.

I am not using any parameters with booting kernel. I have disabled Virtualization in Bios.

Comment: See [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/662678/critical-we-failed-but-the-fail-whale-is-dead-sorry) maybe it'll be helpful

Comment: Thanks @Emil! But, is there a way to know why `09:21:32 gnome-session-b: CRITICAL: We failed, but the fail whale is dead. Sorry....` occurred?  Why this is no Gnome running?

Comment: Try to check the gnome session logs by executing `journalctl /usr/bin/gnome-session`

Comment: Honestly, does not have other idea what can be a root cause